# Error in make install: "cannot copy file"

Tags: make

I am trying to install CLHEP 2.3.4.4 and I am stuck, getting an error in `make install`:

```
[ 99%] Built target exctest3 
[ 99%] Built target exctestNothrow
[100%] Built target testzmex
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/clhep-config
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/home/ivan/CLHEP/2.3.4.4/CLHEP/2.3.4.4-build/clhep-config" to
  "/usr/local/bin/clhep-config".
Makefile:105: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Try `sudo make install`.

To access the `/usr` directory of your installation to store system-wide files there, the installer needs root privileges. Therefore you can not just run plain `make install` as your normal user account but need to use `sudo` to elevate privileges.

Comment: What if I don't want root privileges and only want to compile for the current user?

Comment: @UserRebo Maybe you can try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42569).

Comment: try `sudo make install` where???

Answer (score 2):

If want to install without root / sudo try `DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` option:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/opt
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/opt .
make
make install
```

Consider adding folder to PATH, in order to use it by name only

```
export PATH="$HOME/opt/bin:$PATH" # for binaries
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/opt/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" # for libs
export CPATH="$HOME/opt/include:$CPATH" # for includes
```